# "Страшно испугаться": можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Слово "страшно" в значении "сильно", если не ошибаюсь, тут уже обсуждалось однажды. Но вот как насчет оборота "страшно испугаться"? С одной стороны, на лицо явный плеоназм из серии "страшный ужас", но с другой, вроде как, слово "страшно" употреблено тут в другом значении.
Так вот, является ли выражение "страшно испугаться" грамотным и можно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существование наречия "страшно" подтверждает словарь: С. болит голова. С. хочется есть.

Страшно испугался - это не плеоназм (это "очень испугался"). Формально это не тавтология, так как слова не однокоренные, но в то же время страх и испуг - это синонимы. Соответственно, "страшно испугаться" не используется в нейтральном стиле - это, скорее, разговорный или художественно-экспрессивный стиль.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Тотошка сначала сделал вид, что страшно испугался.

Девочка сказала: «Пишите», ― и он сейчас же сунул в чернильницу свой нос и страшно испугался, когда с носа на бумагу упала чернильная клякса.

"...я страшно испугался: вот-вот сейчас же явится перед нами ненавистный купец, заплатит свои деньги, навсегда похитит с моих глаз это сокровище, которое промелькнет для меня, как неразгаданное видение (Ф. И. Буслаев).

"...он сам страшно испугался, лежит и… и просит послать за доктором (А. П. Чехов).

"Только что выпитый стакан сказался. Митя страшно испугался (Ф. М. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы).

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, можно. Это не плеоназм. "Страшно" здесь – "очень", высшая степень качества. Сравните: страшно красивый.

Comment: Ну, это уже оксюморон какой-то

Comment: Ну и что? Зато выразительный. И главное – так говорят.